# Is using $watch better than using $on and $broadcast?

Tags: angularjs

If I want to call a function in a controller when I make changes in a different controller, I usually use `$on` and `$broadcast`.

However, I've started using `$watch` more recently. Now, I have a variable in a service, for example `this.shouldIReload = false`. Whenever I make a certain change(for example, deleting an item in a modal), I change the value in the service, and using `$watch`, I can call a reload function in another controller. This works.

Which way is better? What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: If you structure your service correctly you shouldn't even have to use `$watch()` explicitly because Angular will handle it during each digest cycle. Personally, I recommend avoiding the use of `$on`, `$broadcast` and `$watch` unless what you are doing simply can't be achieved without using one or more of those methods.